# Grails check if a class has a static variable with a particular value

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a class in grails like:

```
class Autoresponder {
    static String TYPE_NONE = "none"
    static String TYPE_GETRESPONSE = "GetResponse"
    static String TYPE_MAILCHIMP = "MailChimp"
    static String TYPE_AWEBER = "AWeber"
    static String TYPE_INFUSIONSOFT = "InfusionSoft"
    static String TYPE_ICONTACT = "iContact"
    static String TYPE_SENDY = "Sendy"
    static String TYPE_ACTIVECAMPAIGN = "ActiveCampaign"
    static String TYPE_API_ACTIVATE = "activate"
    static String TYPE_ONTRAPORT = "ontraport"

    //rest of code
}
```

I want to simply find that the above class has a static variable with value `AWeber`.
How do I do it? Is there a way to fetch all static user defined variables in a class(and thereby compare each variable's value with what I want)?

**EDIT:**
Due to some technical reasons, I can not change class definition.

Comment: Make it an enum and loop over the enum values

Comment: @Tunaki I can't change class definition.

Comment: Is the class a Groovy or Java class?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore lol its a groovy class. Find a semicolon there :p

Comment: @Neoryder I am yet to test the answers. Will test today and mark as answer what solved my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just iterate over all static fields looking for the one with the desired value. As in the following groovy script example

```
import static java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isStatic

class Autoresponder {
    static String TYPE_NONE = "none"
    static String TYPE_GETRESPONSE = "GetResponse"
    static String TYPE_MAILCHIMP = "MailChimp"
    static String TYPE_AWEBER = "AWeber"
    static String TYPE_INFUSIONSOFT = "InfusionSoft"
    static String TYPE_ICONTACT = "iContact"
    static String TYPE_SENDY = "Sendy"
    static String TYPE_ACTIVECAMPAIGN = "ActiveCampaign"
    static String TYPE_API_ACTIVATE = "activate"
    static String TYPE_ONTRAPORT = "ontraport"
}    

def getStaticAttributeWithValue(Class clazz, Object searchedValue) {
    clazz.declaredFields
        .findAll{ isStatic(it.modifiers) }
        .find { clazz[it.name] == searchedValue }
}

assert getStaticAttributeWithValue(Autoresponder, "AWeber") != null
assert getStaticAttributeWithValue(Autoresponder, "NonExist") == null
```

If the function returns null, there is no static field with that value, otherwise, it will be not null. (actually it will be a object of type [java.lang.reflect.Field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html))

There is another way to fetch all static attributes in your class, that is using groovy MetaClass, but the idea is the same

```
def getStaticAttributeWithValue(Class clazz, Object searchedValue) {
    clazz.metaClass.properties
        .findAll{ it.getter.static }
        .find { clazz[it.name] == searchedValue }
}
```

This way you will get a [groovy.lang.MetaBeanProperty](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/MetaBeanProperty.html) instead

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to use [GrailsClassUtils.getStaticFieldValue](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsClassUtils.html#getStaticFieldValue%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) to see if a Groovy class in Grails has a static property with a given value.

The above utility class has other methods that you may also find helpful.

Comment: getStaticField value would require me to know the variable name. What if I just have the value and I know the value is of type string?

Comment: Ah, well that's easy enough using `metaClass` which is pointed out in another answer already.

Answer (score 1):

Try to go with MetaClass. Something like (not tested... just an idea):

```
String val
if(Autoresponder.metaClass.static.AWeber){
    val = Autoresponder.AWeber
}
```

With MetaClass you can also edit the methods and statics in there. It should also be faster than reflections